# code: 'ERR_LAUNCHER_PATH_NOT_SET' when deploying to heroku with @open-wa/wa-automate library

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, heroku, heroku-cli

So, I want to use @open-wa/wa-automate library to send whatsapp chat after user submit report on my web application and this errors show up. I have set config to the chrome path also the buildpacks but it's not solve yet. And, there is also my dependencies and script on package.json in case there is something need to change,add or update. Is there anything i can do for exampe use Procfile or do npx @open-wa/wa-automate -o or another things to solve this error ?

````
app[web.1]: Error
app[web.1]: at new LauncherError (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:26:22)
app[web.1]: at new ChromePathNotSetError (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:33:9)
app[web.1]: at Object.linux (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-finder.js:128:15)
app[web.1]: at Launcher.getInstallations (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js:130:51)
app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/@open-wa/wa-automate/dist/controllers/browser.js:435:65
app[web.1]: at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
app[web.1]: at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/@open-wa/wa-automate/dist/controllers/browser.js:28:58)
app[web.1]: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
app[web.1]: Error creating client: ChromePathNotSetError
app[web.1]: at new LauncherError (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:26:22)
app[web.1]: at new ChromePathNotSetError (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:33:9)
app[web.1]: at Object.linux (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-finder.js:128:15)
app[web.1]: at Launcher.getInstallations (/app/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/chrome-launcher.js:130:51)
app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/@open-wa/wa-automate/dist/controllers/browser.js:435:65
app[web.1]: at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
app[web.1]: at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/@open-wa/wa-automate/dist/controllers/browser.js:28:58)
app[web.1]: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
app[web.1]: message: 'The CHROME_PATH environment variable must be set to a Chrome/Chromium executable no older than Chrome stable.',
app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_LAUNCHER_PATH_NOT_SET'
app[web.1]: }```

**PLEASE HELP !**

config : 
```CHROME_PATH:          /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome```

And this is my buildpack :

Buildpack URLs

1. heroku/nodejs
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.git
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git

In addition, this is my package.json dependencies and script
"dependencies": {
        "@open-wa/wa-automate": "^4.61.0",
        "argon2": "^0.30.1",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "connect-session-sequelize": "^7.1.5",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
        "express-session": "^1.17.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "sequelize": "^6.25.5",
        "url": "^0.11.0"
    },
"scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
````

Comment: For me the problem was my VPS didn't have chrome installed